# CMOS cleared after power loss, even though I've replaced the battery

Tags: motherboard, bios, battery, cmos, dell-optiplex

One of my PCs will not retain its CMOS settings after power loss. This usually means that the CMOS battery is dead. I verified this with a multimeter on the CMOS battery after I removed it from the board and it was approx 1.5v. I have replaced the CMOS battery with a brand new one which I bought recently (expiry date 2029). I verified that the new CMOS battery has a charge of just over 3V before I installed it into the system, so I know it's good. However, after power loss, this system still loses all of its CMOS settings.

The PC is a Dell OptiPlex 3020. I have another OptiPlex 3020 and it retains it's CMOS settings just fine after power loss.

What could be wrong here?

I've tried:

- Replacing the CMOS battery (twice)
- Swapping the know working battery in from the other PC of the same model
- I've updated the BIOS to the latest version available for this PC's motherboard (A20)
- I've run the onboard Dell diagnostics and it said everything was ok
- I've tried manually clearing the CMOS using the jumpers on the board and then setting things from scratch
- I've removed the motherboard from the chassis and inspected the front and back of the motherboard for any corrosion or bulging capacitors. I did not find any issues.
- I've monitored the positive side of the battery to ground (chassis) and I see that this drops from over 3V to just under 3V fairly quickly. I observed a voltage drop of around 0.002V per minute. I'm assuming that this is not normal. I can't see anything physically wrong with the motherboard that would cause this, though -- there's no visible shorts.
- I've been out to buy a brand new pack of Duracell branded batteries (expiry date 2030). The one that I put in measured 3.3V when I installed it but still the system didn't retain it's CMOS settings. This battery was drained to 3.18V whilst the system was disconnected from power for a short while.

At this stage, I'm not sure if the battery voltage dropping is and issue or not. 3.3V should be plenty for the system to retain it's settings while not connected to mains. To me, it looks like there's a short on the motherboard somewhere that's dropping the voltage across the CMOS when there's no mains, so the CMOS isn't seeing the required voltage to retain anything. Trouble is, I cannot see any signs of anything shorting -- no corrosion, stripped/bare wires or anything like that.

If there's any other info that would be useful, please let me know in the comments so I can add to the question.

Comment: Silly question; did you remove the clear CMOS jumper from the pins?

Comment: Yep, I did remove the jumper afterwards

Comment: Check the battery holder contacts, which could be bent, or shorted. If shorted, it may have drained the new battery.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I've just tried cleaning the contacts and I also bent them slightly so that they apply more pressure on the batter. Still the issue persists.

Comment: Does the battery voltage keep dropping beyond the initially observed drop? I.e. if you measure the voltage after a few hours, what is it?

Comment: @StarCat The battery voltage seems to only drop when the machine is not connected to the mains. As I need this system one and connected to the mains 24/7 it's hard to tell. I've just measured it now and it's approx 3.1V and the system has been on since yesterday evening (around 24 hours).

Answer (score 1):

Possible cause:

Some batteries leak, the liquid that leaks out damages the PCB surrounding it.

So: There may be damaged traces on the PCB.
Check for strange look on the PCB.

Comment: Good idea, but I've just inspected the motherboard on both sides and cannot find any corrosion.

Comment: Any damage, even minuscule?

Comment: No, none whatsoever

Comment: Ok, out of ideas... maybe try to locate the actual IC and replace it. I don't know how possible that is. might differ from one PCB to next, even from same manufacturer.